# Does fixed charge inside the dielectric of a parallel plate capacitor change the overall capacitance value?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, capacitance

The capacitance for a parallel plate capacitor with surface area $A$ separated by a distance $d$ with a dielectric placed between the plates of value $\epsilon$ is expressed as:

$$C=\frac{q}{V}=\frac{\epsilon A}{d}$$

where the steps above can be derived using Gauss' Law. Similarly, the capacitance when a conductor of thickness $b$ is instead placed between the plates ([as derived in the Feynman Lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_10.html)) is expressed as:

$$C=\frac{\epsilon A}{d[1-(b/d)]}$$

My question then is, imagine if instead of a conductor, an amount of fixed charged was placed inside the conductor along with the initial dielectric, would the value of the capacitance change? So to give specifics, imagine a parallel plate capacitor of area $A$ and distance $d$ has a dielectric $\epsilon$ between its plates, and imagine at distance $d/2$ a fixed charge of Q was placed such that Q is evenly distributed across the entire area of the capacitor, would this change the amount of charge $q$ that would reside across the capacitors plates for a given voltage $V$?